# What is the equivalent T-SQL select query for the attached linq query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I am facing some trouble writing where condition in the SQL select statement match the above criteria. Any advice?

```
AllCompany = AllCompany
 .Where(company =>fldSector
 .Contains(company["Sectors"].Replace("|", ","))).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: That's going to have poor performance because SQL server isn't able to effectively search with a leading wildcard. Consider normalizing your data (perhaps a table that suits between Items and Sectors).

Answer (score 1):

There is a [REPLACE()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function in sql-server and it would probably look like this if you do `updating` on your table:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET sectors = REPLACE(sectors,'|',',');
```

See <kbd>**[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5c57/1)**</kbd>

Or if you want simply to `SELECT`, you can use `PATINDEX()`:

```
SELECT sectors  
FROM tableName
WHERE PATINDEX('%|%',sectors) > 0
```

See <kbd>**[Fiddle Demo with PATINDEX](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b94e5/1)**</kbd>